# Sample size for a small proportion

Tags: sample-size, proportion

I'm calculating the required sample size for the following RCT design: the baseline proportion is 3%, and I want to be able to detect a difference of 1ppt with 80% power.

If I use the sample size calculation assuming a normal distribution, the required sample size for Treatment and Control is just over 5000, but I'm just a bit unsure whether I can do this due to the small baseline proportion?

Thanks a lot

Comment: what do you mean "detect a difference of 1ppt " ? from 3% to 4% or to 2%?

Comment: ppt is "percent point"?   I read it as "part per thousand", better to spell out!  You can calculate power using simulation.

Comment: Ppt is percentage point, and the important change would be from 3% to 4%, but impact could be to reduce down below 3% instead.